# how to subtract a specific amount from the COUNT(*) result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to PHP and i want to know how i can subtract a specific amount from the results from counting the total amount of rows in a table. In this case i'd like to minus the value 3 from whatever the value of the total rows is. But i keep getting an error. Below is my code.

```html
$cartwork = $con->query("SELECT count(*) FROM table");

$vs = '3';

$camount = $cartwork - $vs;

echo "$camount";
```

When the code runs i get the error "Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int" what can i do to fix this and get it to work properly.

Comment: do a print_f($cartwork); or var_dump($cartwork); to check what your vairable contains

Comment: You don't need to create a variable to subtract a value. You just need to fetch your result-set first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query returns a result set. You need to parse through the result set(s) in order to access the values returned. That's basically what the error states.
Please see here for documentation on the PHP function for fetching rows:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

So basically you would need

```
$row=$cartwork->mysql_fetch_row();
$cartWork_value = $row[0];
$vs = '3';
$camount = $cartwork_Value - $vs;
echo "$camount";
```

Note - this assumes that you get back exactly one result row (which should be the case with your query).

Comment: And then he can do ($row[0] - 3) to subtract, can't he?

Comment: Yes - I took over the original code, so above 3 is assigned to $vs and then deducted in the next row.

Comment: A) Please don't link to third-rate documentation like w3schools, instead prefer PHP's [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php). B) Don't use the procedural style when the question uses the object-oriented form.

Comment: Sorry, was the quickest I found and also the way I'm used to. I'll try and update.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your query to:

```
$cartwork = $con->query("SELECT count(*)-3 FROM table");
```

It doesn't smell particularly good though.